# How to handle Custom Validation in inline entity Form?

Tags: 8, entities, forms

I'm using Drupal8's inline entity form and is having issue with writing custom validation. I found few links and wasn't helpful at all. Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 7):

You have to use inline form alter for custom validation in module shown below

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function module_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter(&$entity_form, &$form_state) {

  // Added custom validation 
  if ($entity_form['#bundle'] == 'bundle_name') {
    $entity_form['#element_validate'][] = '_custom_validate_function';
  }
}
```

And implement that validation like below.

```
/**
 * Custom validation.
 */
function _custom_validate_function(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

 $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
 $values = $form_state->getValues();
 // or you can use $form_state->getValue('field_name')
 // Validate your functionality

 // Set Error for form
 $form_state->setError($form, t("message"));
 // Note: $name may be unknown in $form_state and
 // $form_state->setErrorByName($name, $message) may suppress the error message.
 // hence use above $form_state->setError()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set Error on inline entity forms is improved by specifying the actual element like this

```
$form_state->setError($form['field_name']['widget'], t("message"));
```

The above will successfully display the message inline.